# Partition SQL result set into chunks

Tags: sql

In preparation for a batch process, I need to partition groups of records in order to run parallel streams of a job.  These records come from a table that could potentially have millions of rows.  My goal is to evenly break up these records (by primary key) into (approximately) even chunks that can then be processed in parallel.  I want to choose the chunk size dynamically.  What may also be noteworthy is that there may be gaps in the primary key sequence.

In other words, given this table, with a predicate denoting the number of chunks and a result set providing the first and last sequence of the chunk:

```
  seq    name   |
-------|--------|
1      | john   |
2      | joe    |
3      | joe    |
4      | joe    |
5      | joe    |
567    | kent   |
568    | katie  |
20000  | sue    |
200016 | jill   |
200027 | bill   |
```

I would get back the following results where (number-of-chunks) -> (first-seq, last-seq):

```
(2) -> (1,5),(567,20027)
(5) -> (1,2),(3,4),(5,567),(568,20000),(200016,200027)
```

Or, as a result set, something like this (when asking for 5 chunks):

```
 first_seq   last_seq 
-----------|----------|
  1        | 2        |
  3        | 4        |
  5        | 567      |
  568      | 200000   |
  20016    | 200027   |
```

I'm assuming some kind of window function is in order here, but I'm not sure how to tackle this. Can anyone assist me with the query?

Comment: can you add the expected output in table format

Comment: what you're calling "chunk-size" appears to be the number of chunks you want, is that right?  (I would normally read "chunk-size" as the number of items to appear in each chunk.)

Comment: Will this be used with SQLServer or MySQL?

Comment: @DaveCosta yeah, you are right, that was mis leading, I'll edit.

Comment: @ChrisduPreez The ideal solution will be DB agnostic, but it has to work on DB2 and Oracle at a minimum.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Updated with an example of a potential result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should work pretty well with most DB systems.

1) Have put `chunk` in fields list to be more verbose; same for the `order by`

2) Have split the sequence up into `10` chunks with ...`(10 / (num_rows +`...

```
select MIN(seq) as first_seq, MAX(seq) as last_seq, chunk from
        /*- Basic grouping formula pseudo: #row_chunk_number = round-up( ( #total_num_chunks / #total_num_rows ) x #current_row_num )
          - The +0.0 is to convert field values to floats
          - floor() + 1 means the same as rounding up ... and im not sure if ceil() exists on all DB systems.
        */
        (select seq, floor(((10 / (num_rows + 0.0)) + 0.0) * (row_num + 0.0)) + 1 as chunk from
        (select 
            seq,
            /*`row_num` is the row number in the sequence range - achieved by iteratively counting all sequences smaller than current (assuming seq is unique and numeric).*/
            (select COUNT(*) from table1 as b where b.seq < a.seq) as row_num,
            /*`num_rows` is the number of rows in the sequence range - added to inner query to prevent cluttering the actual math calc in the outer query (same performance).*/
            (select COUNT(*) from table1 ) as num_rows
        /*dat1 is a derived table of seq (id), num_rows (total number rows) and row_num (row number)*/
        from table1 as a) as dat) as dat1 
group by chunk
order by chunk
```

Comment: This works!  Would you mind adding some comments to the SQL, explaining the logic?  Some of it is a bit unintuitive (but maybe thats just me).

Comment: Have added slightly more comments to my solution. Maybe upvote my answer's usefulness?

Comment: Fantastic!  Up voted and marked as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The NTILE function might work for you in Oracle (I'm not sure about DB2):

```
SELECT seq, ntile( 2 ) over (order by seq) chunk_num
  FROM my_table
```

(where 2 is the number of chunks)

Or to get the results in the layout you described:

```
SELECT chunk_num, MIN(seq), MAX(seq) FROM (
  SELECT seq, ntile( 2 ) over (order by seq) chunk_num
    FROM my_tab
  )
  GROUP BY chunk_num
```

If the number of chunks does not evenly divide the number of rows, it will put the excess into the lower-numbered chunks.

Comment: I remember using this function ages ago, had completly forgot about it. Nice answer.

Comment: This is definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for...... if indeed it is supported by DB2.  Based on the suggestion of using NTILE, I found [this gem](http://wloclawek.wsinf.edu.pl/~kzebrows/SQL/OReilly.SQL.Cookbook.Dec.2005/0596009763/sqlckbk-CHP-12-SECT-8.html) via some quick googling.  I'll check this out tomorrow when I have access to my DB again and see if it works.  Thanks @DaveCosta

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on DB2, so while this would be my preferred solution, @ChrisduPreez's solution is database agnostic.